# Cursor moves to next line in the bullets list or number list SP 2013

Tags: javascript, css, content

In an HTML content field on a page where the custom branding is applied, the cursor is jumping around while editing the UL/OL (Unordered list or Ordered list). If you pressed enter to go to the next line (new LI or bullet/number), the new bullet/number gets created but the cursor jumps back to the previous bullet. Hence unable to add text to the newly created bullets. Even with the arrow keys you can't go to those bullets. Cursor just doesn't stay there.

[image]

Comment: Hey @Ram, could you add more information, please? How are you generating the list of bullets? Any code samples that could help us? It's hard to wrap ones head around the problem without some kind of detailed description.

Comment: I am creating number bullets manually.
Check this is the code snippet-
<div>
   <ol>
      <li>Line 1<br/></li>
      <li>Line 2<br/></li>
      <li>Line 3<br/></li>
      <li>
      </li>
      <li>Line 4<br/></li>
      <li>Line 5<br/></li>
   </ol>
</div>

Comment: Ok, so is that problem with editor you are using? Not sure if it's a programming or tooling issue judging from your update. Also why are you adding <br/> tag within the <li>?

Comment: I have not added those <br/>, While I am adding the bullets to list that time  comes.
So, How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you adding this to SharePoint? Is it in a web part on page? Are you doing that in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I have created content page.
And adding manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45146/discussion-between-cthulhubutt-and-ram).

Comment: @Ram if you add informations to your question do it in the actual question and not in the comments.

Comment: @Mx I was in the chat with Ram in the past 15 minutes discussing this and I simply asked him to use screentogif to record what is happening as it is rather hard to wrap our heads around this issue so hopefully it will shed some light on this mystery.

Comment: Please check the .gif file.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with Chrome.  I had the same problem using the standard content editor webpart in SharePoint 2013, so I tested it on three different servers, and the behavior was exactly the same.  About a half a second after you click next to one of the bullets, the cursor would move either up or down.  If you start typing fast enough you can prevent the cursor from moving, but that's hardly a solution.  I thought that it might have something to do with bootstrap, but it also occurred on the default Seattle master page.

I normally use Chrome, so I decided to test the other browsers, and found that this issue does not occur when using Explorer or Firefox.

Comment: Actually I have checked it lot of times and same thing was happened as you answered.
So, Can we say it's the default functionality or bug of SP?

Comment: It's got to be a bug, although I haven't the faintest idea of what causes it.  I don't think anyone would intentionally make that happen, as it's infuriating.  Fortunately for me in this case most of my users with contribute access don't use Chrome.